# Is it possible to see all edited styles in Firefox developer tools?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

My preferred CSS workflow (at least when tweaking existing CSS) is to edit directly in the browser using the 3-panel Inspector panel, then copy the edited styles to my stylesheet.

Sometimes I'll edit the styles for many elements and forget that I edited some element (since you can only see if it's edited AFAICT by selecting exactly that element and looking for rules with a green bar to the left). Then I'll fail to manually copy that element's style changes to my stylesheet and, on reload, lose the changes.

Is there somewhere I can see *all* the places where I've edited styles using Inspector -- including adding new rules -- so that I can copy them all at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Firefox devtools now have a "Changes" tab with a Git-like panel showing all your changes.

[image: Changes tab in Firefox]

Comment: Yes! This is just the info I was looking for. Hope this feature makes it into stable Firefox soon.

Comment: Yes, this will indeed ship with Firefox 65, which was just in Nightly last week, and is about to reach Beta this week. So if you either download Nightly or Beta, you will have the new Changes panel (no need to set `devtools.inspector.changes.enabled` anymore in fact, this is now visible by default).